# How do I find and disable extensions providing the same completions in VS-Code IntelliSense?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, svelte

I'm getting duplicated entries in the auto-completion for HTML attribute values.

[image: Multiple Entries for 'input type' attribute]

This happens in a [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) file. I have the `svelte.svelte-vscode` extension installed.
It does not happen in an HTML file.
I don't have an extension for HTML: serching an extension with "@installed html" returns nothing. Maybe the feature is embedded in VS-Code?

Ideally, how can I find and select (in general, i.e. any language) among different installed extensions that provide the same auto-completion support?

If there is no general way that works in any language, how can I find and select only one extension that provides auto-completion for HTML attributes in Svelte files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug with the Svelte extension and should be fixed now.

Comment: I confirm it's fixed in v102.4.0